# Predicting rate of inventory depletion based on previous sales

Tags: mysql, sql, prediction

Suppose I have an `order_items` table that tracks sales of `items`:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `order_items` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `order_items_order_id_index` (`order_id`),
  KEY `order_items_item_id_index` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

How would I create a query that can return the estimated rate of inventory quantity depletion based on past sales for a particular time period?

For instance, if `item_id` `1` sells half its stock in 2 weeks (based on `created_at` timestamp), how would I put that into a query that would tell me that in another 2 weeks there should be no quantity remaining?

Would it also be possible to group depletion rates by time spans in a single query?

Here is my Fiddle for this:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c568f

Comment: So basically, you want to know how many sales there were for a particular item in the last X weeks and use that number against the current stock to see how much will be left in X weeks time?

Comment: @2unco basically, yes. And to be able to group them to analyze trends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a less basic query that gets you all items, their current stock, how much they've sold in the last two weeks and how much stock there'll be after 2 more weeks if it keeps up:

```
SELECT i.id,
    i.stock AS current_stock,
    COALESCE(SUM(o.quantity), 0) AS orders_last_2_weeks,
    i.stock - COALESCE(SUM(o.quantity), 0) AS stock_after_2_weeks
FROM items AS i
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items o
    ON o.item_id = i.id
    AND o.created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
GROUP BY i.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08754/6

I had to tweak the dates on your Fiddle as none of the orders were ending up in the last two weeks.

Comment: PS: just took out that variable I was using. I didn't have time to test it and it looked like it was causing some problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic query that gets you the number of items sold and how many days it took to sell them:

```
SELECT Item_ID
      ,SUM(Quantity) As TotalSold
      ,DATEDIFF(MAX(Created_AT),MIN(Created_At)) AS Days_To_Sell 
FROM order_items
GROUP BY Item_ID
```

If you want more complex analysis rather than simple depletion rate, you'd probably want to incorporate a calendar table so you can easily break down all sales by item for given time periods, but you could also add date parts to your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`, like `WEEK()`, `MONTH()`, etc.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fac002/4/0)

Comment: How would such a calendar table be implemented? I can't quite visualize what you mean.

Comment: @eComEvo Create a table to hold dates and information about them. You can find scripts available, [like this one](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519). Then you join your sales to the date table and can easily do `GROUP BY quarter` or `WHERE weekday='monday'` or whatever.

Comment: @eComEvo A calendar table can be just a list of dates in order, or it can have many other fields, like flags for holidays and other details you may or may not care about.  Joining to a calendar table can be more efficient if you need that level of detail.

Comment: Used the other solution for now since it was simpler, but I will likely use this more advanced calendar option down the road so I've upvoted this response. Appreciate it!